# A change that affects all the file?

Tags: changes

assume I want to replace the command `\tilde` by `\widetilde` in my latex file through all the file. Is there a way to do so such that the change affects all the text but avoiding to make all the changes by hand?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde}` on preamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.TX! Search and replace? ;-)  Brute force: `\renewcommand{\tilde}[1]{\widetilde[#1]}` or a `\let` statement

Comment: You might also `\let\oldtilde\tilde` before redefining it to wide tilde.  That way, if you ever needed a single exception to the rule, you could call on `\oldtilde` and get the original behavior.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.